# Menu key not working in popupscreen

Tags: blackberry, keyboard, textfield, blackberry-storm

there is `PopupScreen` in my application .. `PopupScreen` have some `Field` like `BasiceditTextfield` and `Buttonfield` .

when i click on my `BasiceditTextfield` virtual keyboard open automatically in my 9550 Storm but when i click on Device Menu key nothing happen. i cant hide virtual keyboard ..

how to hide that .?

Comment: In popup screen Menu doesn't work that's why BB activates the "Show keyboard" directly. when you close the popup screen then only it close the keyboard.

Comment: when iclick on edittextfield keyboard open directly ..but i cant hide it using Menu key ..

Answer (score 0):

Use this.
This will enable Menuscreen and disable back key of the device.

```
    protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int status) 
    {
      if(keycode==1769472)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Using constant values like 1769472 in your code is considered bad practice, isn't this a composite of KeyPad constants?

Comment: i implemented this code in my popupscreen . when i click on my edittextfield keyboard open automatically ..but when i click on device menu key to hide keyboard not open menu options .. how to handle this ? and what is the "1769472" ?

Comment: Write this code in your screen from where you call popup screen.

Comment: of course the magic number is a keycode and a set of flags! the test should be: if(Keypad.key(keycode) == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE